# How to draw item like this below in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My purpose is I want to draw an Item like below image :

[image]

But it is really difficult to draw an image like below that it has draw on another view. It's not an image, for example the value is "off" and this value depend on the value of string if we set long value it will expand.

[image]

Could you let me know the solution, how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to put a badge on top of a view, right?

Check out http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jsbadgeview

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stackoverflow

The method you're looking for is the following:

```
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets (iOS5 or later)
```

for earlier iOS versions you have:

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't want to use UIImage to draw but I want to draw it with methode "drawRect:(CGRect)rect" or layoutSubViews. It's possible to do that ?